# Parametrization of a circular arc in terms of the angle between the tangent line and the $x$-axis

Tags: calculus, parametric

I'm struggling with this problem:

"Find a parametrization of the first quadrant part of the circular arc $x^2 + y^2 = a^2$ in terms of the angle between the tangent line and the positive x-axis, oriented counterclockwise."

I drew a sketch of the first quadrant in the $xy$-plane, and specified an arbitrary point $(x, y)$ on the arc. Then I sketched the tangent at that point, making an obtuse angle $\theta$ with the positive $x$-axis.

I'm not sure how to do the parametrization though, any ideas/help?

Comment: There is a triangle with angles $90^\circ, 180^\circ-\theta$ and $\alpha$ where $\theta$ is the given angle. Using $\alpha$, you should easily find a parameterisation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

Look at the figure.
The angles $\theta$ are the same because formed by orthogonal straight lines. Now looking at the blue circle you see that:
$
OA= \sin \theta
$
and
$
XA= \cos \theta
$

Using this result you can parametrize the arc as $(\sin t, -\cos t)$ with $ 0 \le t \le \theta $.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Can I ask what program you used to draw that? I'm looking for a geometry-like program which is compatible with LaTeX aswell.

Comment: Welcome. I use LaTex with the pakage Pgfplots: http://pgfplots.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 1):

Call the tangent point $P$, the origin $O$ and the point of intersection on the $x$-Axis $Q$. The triangle $\Delta OQP$ is a right triangle (Because of the tangent property, $\angle OPQ = 90^\circ$). We know that the arc is parameterised by
$$\phi(\xi) = (\cos \xi, \sin \xi) \qquad \xi\in [0, \angle QOP]$$
But $\angle QOP = 90^\circ - \underbrace{\angle PQO}_{=180^\circ - \theta} = \theta - 90^\circ$, where $\theta$ is the given obtuse angle.